# How to redirect on User based?

Tags: redirection

I am new to drupal So
I want to redirect the user based on login 
Say,
if there is an Anonymous user, he will be redirected to specific page,
and if is an Authorized user along with login id and password, then he will be redirected to other specific page using script

Comment: In which condition, you want to redirect user? Like, you want to redirect user on form submit or viewing any page?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module and create redirect rules.

Project page says

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules).

Example use cases

- Build flexible content publishing workflows changes
- Send customized mails to notify your users about important
- **Create custom redirections**, system messages, breadcrumbs, ...
- Build an eCommerce store using Drupal Commerce And many more...

Answer (score 0):

Simply implement `hook_preprocess_page()` in `template.php` file and add your business logic: example

```
function MY_THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if(CONDITION /* additional condition, e.g. $variables['is_front'] */) {
    if(user_is_anonymous()) {
      drupal_goto('node/13'); //change the url, with yours
    }
    else {
      drupal_goto('node/7'); //change the url, with yours
    }
  }
}
```

if you are implementing this hook for the first time then you need to flussh the cache.